# Spring-Boot app stdout written to log file on Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-logs

I have a Spring-Boot application that I have running in a Docker container.  When I run the app standalone outside of the container, all the logs are written to `stdout`.  I need to get the app `stdout` written to a file on my Docker container.

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  meanwhileinhell:
    image: azul/zulu-openjdk-centos:latest
    container_name: "meanwhile-in-hell"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - logfiles:/var/log/meanwhileinhell/
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    networks:
      - default

volumes:
  logfiles:
    driver: local

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: meanwhileinhell-network
```

I can get the directory specified to be created ok, but there is nothing in it.  Can someone help me as to how to get this to write to file?  I haven't been able to find anything on SO or general searching.  `docker logs -f <container-id>` shows the same information I am looking to write.

Comment: Docker won’t do this on its own.  You need to [configure an alternate log driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/), or else set up your process to write to a file instead of (or in addition to) stdout, or run an external process that knows about the Docker internal log format.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I'll look into that.